# How to enable greyed toolbox items in VS2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, toolbox

I created new project using 'Windows Forms App (.net Framework)'. Target Framwork 4.6. Form1.vb was created and design view shown.
As first step. I want to put a menustrip on the form, but all items under Navigation in toolbox are grayed out. Assume I have to add a reference - if so - which one? NuGet package?
Spent a couple of days searching on inet but found no answer.
My experience is VB6, new on VS and have to rewrite old VB-code.

---

The app is not running - the attempt to put the menu was the very first thing I did after the creation finished.

A screenshot follows here,
[image]

Comment: Please post a screenshot. I've never seen greyed-out items in the Toolbox: if something isn't available then it's usually not visible at all.

Comment: Is your application running? If yes, this might be the issue why they are all disabled.

Comment: Just edited my question - screenshot included.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
The menus etc was found under another heading - Menus & Toolbars further down in the toolbox.
Sorry for disturbing and thank you for attempt to help me.